# How to add Custom subject in Paypals Notification of payment received email

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I want to have subject of email containing invoice number.

Currently i am getting only Notification of payment received as a subject.

How can i add custom subject (in my case addition of invoice number) in Paypal Notification email of payment recieved?

Please help.